# Bracket notation on a matrix. What is $[A]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I supose that this could be a silly question. But I don't know how to interpretate this term because this is the first time that I see this notation.

Normally I used the bracket of two matrixes as the commutator $[A,B]$

But I found in university notes the notation for a unique matrix $[A]$ and I don't know what is the definition. And obviously if I try to search in google what is [ ] when apply to matrixes all sites refer to the commutator.

For example a context where this notation is used is for the identity,

$$[AB]=[A][B]$$

Comment: We may need more context to help you.

Comment: I added a last line to the post with an example where this notation is used, in a identity

Comment: Are you sure $A$ and $B$ are matrices? When $A$ is a linear map and a fixed base is chosen, $[A]$ is sometimes used to denote the matrix associated to $A$. Then, for example, $[AB] = [A][B]$ is the theorem that says that matrix product corresponds to maps composition.

Comment: @jjagmath I like to think about $[AB]=[A][B]$ as the _definition_ of matrix multiplication, and the standard entry-based formula as the theorem. But to each their own. I do agree with your notational hypothesis, though.